# Django URL pattern with combination of words and numbers in any order

Tags: regex, django-urls

I am trying to build a URL pattern in Django that can allow the following variations:

example:

- folder/9/
- folder/word/
- folder/word_word/
- folder/word_word1098/
- folder/word-word/
- folder/word-word-9/
- folder/wo3rd/
- folder/w/

or perhaps I should just allow any char/digit for that second position like:

```
folder/[anything_in_any_anyorder_here]/
```

any suggestions?

Comment: how about: `^folder/[^/]+/$`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
    /*([a]|[^a])*/